# Add clothes (normal mesh) to a person mesh with armature

Tags: animation, armature

I have a fully rigged person:
[image]

in adams costume (means naked, like god(=me) created him).

Now I have a t-shirt mesh.

[image]

How do I make that the shirt also reacts to the Armature? (bending and so on) and avoid as much as possible that the naked body is seen?

edit:

> Ok I managed to do this by select the shirt and the armature (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to group them in empty group.

> Then select the body and shift select the shirt and then go to weight paint (where edit mode and object mode is).

but now I get some visual errors:

[image]

With nearest vertex the shirt reacts to the armature bend/rotations and so on, but looks crap.

[image]

With the option "Topology" the shirt looks good, but it doesn't react to the armature bendings.

I am missing something right? You know it right? You'll tell me right?

Thx

Comment: Maybe watch this video first, then tell if you still have a problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg

Comment: Also you could share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.com/